# How to atomically reset a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, atomic

We have [atomic access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)  to `shared_ptr`s but I cannot see how to atomically reset them: what am I missing?

Comment: You can set a `shared_ptr` construct with `nullptr`.

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you, this seems quite appropriate, I would make it as _the_ answer

Comment: @Jarod42 please be more explicit

Comment: It is equivalent to StoryTeller's answer (with `nullptr` instead of `{}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `atomic_exchange` with a default constructed `shared_ptr`:

```
atomic_exchange(&ptr, {});
```